# Select all rows between the output of nested select queries and the output + 'n'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to simplify a query that I have written that will select a particular sequence number, such as 1 and then select all of the rows that are greater and equal to the outputted sequence number plus 'n'. For example Select all rows between sequence number 1 and sequence number 5. The data-set has 20k rows so I will not know the sequence number initially.

```
select sequence,line_id,direction,stop_id,stop_name 
from bus_data.bus_locations as stoplist
where line_id ="39a" 
  and direction= "Outbound" 
  and sequence >=
                (SELECT sequence 
                FROM bus_data.bus_locations as depart
                where line_id = "39a"
                and stop_id= 786
                )
  and sequence <= 
               (SELECT sequence + 5 
                FROM bus_data.bus_locations as arrive
                where line_id = "39a"
                and stop_id= 786
                )
order by sequence;
```

I currently have a working query but feel that it is not efficient due to consisting of  three selections from the same table.

```
Sequence  line_id  direction  stop_id  stop_name
19        39a      Outbound   786      Embassy of Malta
20        39a      Outbound   793      Dawson Street
21        39a      Outbound   1808     Morgan Place
22        39a      Outbound   7389     Navan Road
23        39a      Outbound   7586     National Gallery
24        39a      Outbound   7587     Science Gallery
```

I currently have a working query but feel that it is not efficient due to consisting of  three selections from the same table. The table below shows the output from the above query. Any suggestions that would not require selecting from the whole table would be greatly beneficial.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a *clear* explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select bl.*
from (select sequence, line_id, direction, stop_id, stop_name,
             max(case when stop_id = 786 then sequence end) over (partition by line_id) as the_sequence
      from bus_data.bus_locations bl
      where line_id = '39a' 
     ) bl
where sequence >= the_sequence and
      sequence <= the_sequence + 5;
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, would you consider this solution to have a significantly greater efficiency than the one provided in my question.

Comment: @steve2020 . . . With the right indexes on the table, both should be pretty fast.  This might be marginally faster, but you probably would not notice it on a query returning 6 rows for a single route.